# Updating the datalist in a RadComboBox

Tags: asp.net, radcombobox

So I'm just struggling with a lot of little things in the web app so I'm checking up with all kinds of stuff to make sure i'm not breaking it cause of stupid problems.

At some point in my web app (trying to keep it mostly Asynchronous) I have to update the list in my RadComboBox because something was added. Do I just need to call RadComboBox.DataBind() again? Since I don't explicitly use its datasource(I do it in the manual insert using a string fashion) object to insert my new record do I need to tell that to update? The list just doesn't seem to update when i just call databind so I feel like i need to have the datasource recheck for entries or SOMETHING

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything that's going on, could you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal way is to use the NeedDataSource event to setup your datasource.

When you want to rebind, all you have to do is call the DataBind() method.

Answer (score 0):

I just have encountered that problem with my application and I managed to solve it by wrapping the Combobox in an update panel:

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server">
                    <telerik:RadComboBox
                     ID="txtSearch" runat="server"
                     Width="120px" Height="25px"
                     EmptyMessage="Type a Taxonomy"
                     ShowToggleImage="false"  ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="false" AllowCustomText="true" MarkFirstMatch="true"
                     >
                 </telerik:RadComboBox>
                 </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

and also dont 4get to add the Update Panel in the AJAX SCript manager as follows;

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="RadAjaxManager1">
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1"> 
                <UpdatedControls> 
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="txtSearch" /> 
                </UpdatedControls> 
            </telerik:AjaxSetting> 

            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

And to further make sure that things are updated right , so everytime an item is added to the Source that is bound to the ComboBox then u have to call DataBind();

The Above method update the control using Ajax which means u dont have to do full page post back...

I hope I could help.